# Как проверить что в тексте ровно 4 цифры?

Tags: c#

```
      public static bool ValidatePin(string pin)
      {
         return Regex.IsMatch(pin, "^[0-9]{4}$|^[0-9]{6}$");
      }
```

> Wrong output for "1234\n"
>     Expected: False
>     But was:  True

Как сделать так, что бы пропускало исключительно если цифры занимают всю строку. Или 4 цифры или 6. И не пропускать с пробелом или переносом каретки.

Comment: ну а что вас смущает? ваш regex пропускает 4 и 6 значные числа

Comment: пропускает также "1234 " как исключить?

Comment: что исключить? 1234? Все числа? Все четырехзначные числа? Какая у вас задача и что вы сами пробовали с ней?

Comment: @tym32167 он говорит что не должно пропускать 4 числа и пробел в конце как правильный ответ

Comment: исключить в этом же выражении символы пробелов или переноса строки которые могут идти после цифр. Исключить все кроме 4 и 6 значащих цифр. Пробовал на codewars.com выдает вот эту ошибку - Wrong output for "1234 " Expected: False But was: True

Comment: попробовал в студии "1234\n" выдает true

Comment: вопрос почему пропускает \n?

Comment: А зачем тут такие сложности? Это обычное int, переделайте вводимые данные с string на int, либо если не можете, то `int.TryParse()` в помощь...

Answer (score 3):

Не спец по Regex, но вы же можете и без него обойтись, например

```
public static bool ValidatePin2(string pin)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(pin)) return false;
    if (pin.Length!=4 && pin.Length!=6) return false;
    return pin.All(char.IsDigit);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо работает. Хотел разобраться с Regex.

Comment: @Chiplid скорее всего, в выражении `"1234\n"` якорь `$` находится [между цифрами и переносом строки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/anchors-in-regular-expressions#end-of-string-or-line-), потому оно срабатывает.

Comment: @tym32167, поведение $ может зависеть от флага `multiline`

Comment: @Grundy в данном случае одинаково работает, что с флагом multiline, что singleline, что без флагов

Comment: решение ему не подойдет т.к. фишка кодварс в том что бы написать и красивый и короткий код одновременно. Но вообще решение делает нужную задачу :)

Comment: @Andrew так это самое эффективное решение, оно по скорости работы уделает регулярки без напряга, если это не красота, то я не знаю, что есть красота :)

Answer (score 1):

вот с этим выражение работает правильно `@"^[0-9]{4}\z|^[0-9]{6}\z"`

Comment: `\z` - правильное решение. Может кто сподобится дать пояснение, почему именно. Можно сделать перевод [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2707935/5045688).

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку Perl возвращает строку с новой строкой в конце при чтении строки из файла, механизм регулярных выражений Perl соответствует $ в позиции перед разрывом строки в конце строки, даже если multi-line mode выключен. Perl также соответствует $ в самом конце строки, независимо от того, является ли этот символ разрывом строки. Поэтому ^\d+$ соответствует 123 независимо от того, является ли подстрока 123 или 123\n.
Большинство современных вариантов регулярных выражений скопировали это поведение. Это включает в себя .NET.
Если требуется соответствие только в абсолютном конце строки, используйте \z (нижний регистр z вместо верхнего регистра Z). \A\d+\z не соответствует 123\n. 
перевел вот отсюда https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html